# Permission Representation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm currently implementing permissions into an application and are trying to save this onto a database using Hibernate. There are modules with commands and the permissions are also categorized using possible-null role, text channel and role+text channel.

Therefore I want to achieve the following:

- You can either deny/allow modules or commands
- You can allow/deny them by server, by server role, by text channel, or by server role and text channel or for a specific user
- There are also general permissions, that are plain string key-value

I created the following class for it:

```
@Entity
public class Permission implements IPermission {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    
    @Column
    private long guildId;
    
    @Column
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Permission.Type type; // GENERAL, GLOBAL, SERVER, ROLE, ROLECHANNEL
    
    @Column
    private String permissionKey;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private long channelId;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private long roleId;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private long userId;
    
    @Column
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Tribool action; // TRUE, NEUTRAl, FALSE
    
    @Override
    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    @Override
    public long getGuildId() {
        return this.guildId;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChannelId() {
        return this.channelId;
    }

    @Override
    public long getRoleId() {
        return this.roleId;
    }

    @Override
    public long getUserId() {
        return this.userId;
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<String> getModule() {
        if(this.permissionKey.startsWith("module.")) {
            return Optional.of(this.permissionKey.split(".")[1]);
        } else {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<String> getCommand() {
        if(this.permissionKey.startsWith("command.")) {
            return Optional.of(this.permissionKey.split(".")[1]);
        } else {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Tribool getAction() {
        return this.action;
    }
    
    public static enum Type {
        GENERAL,
        GLOBAL,
        SERVER,
        ROLE,
        CHANNEL,
        ROLECHANNEL
    }

}
```

But I don't know if this a good way of saving it.

Comment: How would this be used? For a proper review, we'll need to see how you're currently using this to make sense of whether it's a good system or not.